# How to identify which sets genenrate Borel Sigma Algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets

I have recently started a graduate course on Probability Theory and have been introduced to Borel $\sigma$ - Algebra. But I am having a hard time understanding it 'fully'. I understood the definition but I can't seem to figure out which sets can generate Borel $\sigma$ - Algebra and which can't.

To make things easier for me, I have assumed that for all purposes Borel $\sigma$ - Algebra contains almost everything in **R**.
For example,check this [Question on Borel Sigma Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M57cY.png)

According to me all options are correct but I don't have proper reasoning behind selecting all the 4 options. I would really appearicate any help and hints in this regard.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I understand, but please bear with me for the first time. In the mean time, I will learn Latex and get better at it.

Answer (score 1):

Only the sets 1. and 3. generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, set 2. doesn't generate any intervals, and sets generated by 4. will all stick around $0$.

Comment: More presicely 2) generates the sigma algebra of countable sets and their complements.